# How to import a file from Google Cloud Storage to H2O running in R

Tags: google-cloud-storage, h2o

I would like to import a csv file from my Google Cloud Storage bucket into H2O running in R locally (h2o.init(ip = "localhost")).

I tried following the instructions at http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cloud-integration/gcs.html?highlight=environment.

I can already upload csv files from R to GCS and vice-versa using the R package cloudml. So I am reasonably sure I have the authorizations set correctly.

I have tried using `Sys.setenv(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/full/path/to/auth.json")`. I tried using the terminal from Rstudio to do the same thing: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/full/path/to/auth.json"`. I also tried `gcloud auth application-default login` using the terminal from Rstudio.

But in every case, I could not make this work, from within Rstudio:

```
h2o.init()
h2o::h2o.importFile(path = "gs://[gcs_bucket]/[tbl.csv], 
                    destination_frame = "tbl_from_gcs")
```

H2O throws the error:

```
Error in h2o.importFolder(path, pattern = "", destination_frame = destination_frame,  : 
   all files failed to import
```

If I turn on logging (`h2o::h2o.startLogging("logfile")`), it shows:

```
GET       http://localhost:54321/3/ImportFiles?path=gs%3A%2F%2F[gcs_bucket]%2F[tbl.csv]&pattern=
postBody: 

curlError:         FALSE
curlErrorMessage:  
httpStatusCode:    200
httpStatusMessage: OK
millis:            182

{"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"ImportFilesV3","schema_type":"ImportFiles"},"_exclude_fields":"","path":"gs://[gcs_bucket]/[tbl.csv]","pattern":"","files":[],"destination_frames":[],"fails":["gs://[gcs_bucket]/[tbl.csv]"],"dels":[]}
```

(Obviously, I changed the bucket name and table name, but hopefully you get the idea.)

I am running h2o version 3.26.0.2 in R 3.6.1 and Rstudio 1.2.1578. (I am running Rstudio server in Docker on my local server using rocker/tidyverse:latest, FYI.)

If anyone could walk me through the steps to authenticate H2O so it can access GCS buckets directly, I would appreciate it. I know I could use cloudml or googleCloudStorageR as a workaround, but I would like to be able to use H2O directly so I can more easily switch from a local H2O cluster to a cloud H2O cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution to this authentication issue: Because I am running h2o in Docker swarm, I can set an environment variable for the container in Docker Compose.

The relevant parts of the docker compose file look like this:

```
environment:
  - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/run/secrets/google_auth_secret
secrets:
  - google_auth_secret
...

secrets:
  google_auth_secret:
    file: ./gcloud_auth.json
```

Where gcloud_auth.json is the credentials file described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) for your GCS bucket.